# How to Increase text size only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a code by which i increase the size of text which is in text area and i am able to do this by  given code but here is one problem with me that when increase size of text  it increase also the size of text area and i do not want  this and also want to make text area scrollable

code is given below:

```
<HTML>
<head>


<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


<script>
$(function () {
    $('select[name="font"]').on('change', function () {
      $('textarea').css('font-family', this.value);

    });
});
</script>
</head>



<body>
Select Programming font:
<select name="font">
    <option value="arial">arial black</option>
    <option value="tahoma">tahoma</option>
    <option value="times new roman">times new roman</option>
    <option value="calibri">calibri</option>
</select>

<select onchange="$('#txt').css('font-size', event.target.value + 'px')">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>

<br>EnterValue:
<textarea id="txt" rows="4" cols="50">Test Test</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check my solution if you don't want to set fixed width and height to your `textarea`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use css `resize:none;overflow:auto;width:100px;height:50px` with textarea

```
<textarea id="txt" rows="4" cols="50" style="resize:none;overflow:auto;width:300px;height:50px">Test Test</textarea>
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/9BGT2/

Comment: how can i use this dear can u tell me

Answer (score 2):

Give your textarea specific dimensions using CSS. You can then set the overflow property to auto, which will make the browser automatically render a scrollbar where it is appropriate:

```
#txt{
    height:40px;
    width:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GyXh3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="txt" rows="4" cols="50" style="width:400px;height:100px">Test Test</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width and height of `textarea` before changing your font size then set it back to the `textarea`:

```
$(function () {
    var width = $('textarea').width(),
        height = $('textarea').height();
    $('select[name="font"]').on('change', function () {
        $('textarea').css('font-family', this.value);
        $('textarea').width(width);
        $('textarea').height(height);
    }).change();
});
```

This solution does not require you to set fixed width and height for your `textarea`

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrfrY/)**